# React useState value incorrect on socket.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm new to `socket.io` and I'm trying to implement a simple notification.

My problem is that I execute `handleClick` function to turn `open` to a true value and when `socket.on` run its reading incorrect/default value of the `open`.

**Notification.js**

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    if (!open) {
        setOpen(true) // set open to true
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("notification", function (data) {
        console.log('SOCKET', open) // idk why this is reading false
    })
}, [])
```

**EDIT**

Here's my `use-case` `handleClick` func is where user load his/her notification that will set `open` to true and when `socket` run it will check if `open` is true and dispatch the new notification to existing notification array

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    if (!open) {
        setOpen(true) // set open to true
        dispatch(getNotifications(params)) // load user notifications
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("notification", function (data) {
        console.log('SOCKET', open) // returning false always
        notificationData(data.data)
    })
}, [])

const notificationData = ({ sender, message, notif }) => {
    setNotifCounter(notifCounter => notifCounter + 1)
    setNotification(_.startCase(sender) + ' - ' + message, 'info')
    if (open) { // check if user already loaded his/her own notification
        dispatch(getNewNotif(notif)) // push to array to avoid duplicate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An effect with an empty dependency array (`[]`) will only run the effect once when the component mounts. Instead, add `open` to the dependency array so the effect is triggered on mount ***and*** on state update of `open`. The issue is that the current value of `open` is inclosed in the `socket.on` callback, so when state updates the callback needs to re-enclose `open`.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    if (!open) {
        setOpen(true) // set open to true
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("notification", function (data) {
        console.log('SOCKET', open);
    })
}, [open]) // <-- add open to effect dependency
```

or you can externally defines the callback

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    if (!open) {
        setOpen(true) // set open to true
    }
};

const socketOnHandler = data => console.log('SOCKET', open);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("notification", socketOnHandler)  // <-- use callback
}, [])
```

Comment: I tried this now and its logging 2x 1st log `SOCKET false` 2nd `SOCKET true` which is now displaying 2 times the notification for the user that only needs one time.

Comment: I tried the external callback but its still returning `false`

Comment: Seems it is receiving a message and `open` is false and some time later after something is clicked a second message is received and `open` is now true. Can you provide a more complete picture of your component code and use-case, i.e. reproduction steps?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the proper way. To make it work, when you put socket.on into  useEffect without dependency, it looks resolve the issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("notification", function (data) {
        console.log('SOCKET', open) // idk why this is reading false
    })
});
```

One more time, I am not sure this way is the proper way.